# Quarkus 400/Bad_Request shows raw html on browser

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

I am building a simple Quarkus project.

I have a greeting resource class

```
public class GreetingResource {
    String htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
            "<html lang=\"en\">\n" +
            "<head>\n" +
            "    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n" +
            "    <title>Title</title>\n" +
            "</head>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "Hello !\n" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>";
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response get() {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(htmlString).build();
    }
}
```

This code renders fine on a browser under `localhost:8080/hello`.
However, when I change the response status code to `BAD_REQUEST`, it just displays the raw  `htmlString`.

is there a way so that it renders properly with a 400 request? Eventually, I want to render the error myself using `quarkus qute`